# What does "repo collab" tag mean in github?

Tags: github

What does "repo collab" tag mean in github? It appears right next my userid for every comment and checkin.

Comment: This question is better for either [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com) (since it's not dealing with coding but how the interface/accounts work) or direct to GitHub:Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you've been added as a collaborator for that repository.

Comment: Setting someone as "collaborator" - is it some sett in git ?

Comment: It means that your account has been given rights to make changes to the repository on that particular Github remote, it's not in Git itself. It's a setting in that Github repo.